# Cant dual boot Debian Jessie and Kali rolling

Tags: linux, debian, multi-boot, grub, kali-linux

I had a successful build of Debian Jessie on my laptop. Then i decided to dual boot Debian with Kali rolling. I made a bootable usb via rufus (on my windows machine) and started. At first it didnt boot on kali even though i had external device as #1 priority to boot and after 2-3 more tries to boot from the usb even grub from Debian installation disappeared. How can i make this dual boot work?

Comment: just to be clear...you cant into live system from usb? or you have installed both OS systems and cannot boot into both? or you can boot into one not the other OS?

Comment: i couldnt boot into debian nor install kali. But i reinstalled grub now so i can boot into debian. Kali is only in the usb stick.

Comment: Disable the secure boot from the BIOS settings

Comment: I had it disabled from the 1st moment. It's not secure boot the problem here.